# How to associate a struct with object in Obj-C's runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

How to use `objc_setAssociatedObject` to associate with the object?

```
OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value` must be an Objective-C object. You need to wrap the struct in an Objective-C class. You could use [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue?language=objc) for this.

```
StructType s = ...;
NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&s objCType:@encode(StructType)];
objc_setAssociatedObject(obj, SPECIAL_KEY, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

...

NSValue* value = objc_getAssociatedObject(obj, SPECIAL_KEY);
StructType s;
[value getValue:&s];
```